# Passive HDMI-VGA cable?

Tags: hdmi, vga, cable, adapter, display-adapter

A friend of mine has this cable, which he bought from an international supermarket chain store - I don't expect them to buy useless crap.

It appears to be a totally passive cable, but it's an HDMI->VGA adapter. How can this even work? Didn't work when connecting my laptop to a projector but he assured that the cable worked for him when he used it on his laptop.

[image: visually clear VGA to DHMI passive cable]

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/1551167/under-what-circumstances-will-a-passive-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-work) - possibly this is a dupe of that but I'm not confident enough to modhammer this closed

Comment: @JourneymanGeek absolute dupe!

Comment: unable to close as dupe since the other question is unanswered

Answer (score -1):

Those kind of cables are complete sheet for sure.

But now, reading through [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-troubleshoot-a-HDMI-to-VGA-cable-that-is-not-working), I found out that it wasn't possible to make them work, since HDMI is digital and VGA is analog if the cable isn't an active one.

If the cable is fully passive, it's impossible to set up the 2 connections to work.